Confused on a recent quiz question involving complex numbers. Is 0 a purely imaginary number, any way to prove it with simple methods?
The question went as such:
$$ a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$$

When $a=0$, the complex number $a+bi$ is always imaginary. True or False?

I answered "True" to this question, and was quite confident in my answer, as I recalled that a complex number is considered purely imaginary if the real part is $0$ which fits the statement above. Similarly, I thought of the Argand diagram and how whenever the real part is $0$, the points go up and down the $\mathbb{I}$ axis, which would be considered purely imaginary. But my teacher marked it wrong, stating that the answer is False. I won't be able to see him until the end of this week, and I really want to get this question answered. Im sure he is thinking of the edge case of $b=0$ in which the whole expression would be $0$ but wouldn't that still be intersecting and lying on the imaginary axis?
I have read through some other posts on this site, and found some good conclusions of $0$ being purely imaginary and purely real. Although this makes sense, I want to make sure I am not missing anything before consulting with my teacher on this question.

This really depends on definitions. "Imaginary" in this context, I would think, can be defined either way. It seems like a dumb question, unless you specifically covered this in class at some point.

In other words, absent the context of clear definitions, it could be either way.

Yeah, there's no way to "prove" is either way - it just depends on how the definition is stated.

As other commenters have stated, you'll ultimately have to see how your professor or textbook defines "imaginary." For what it's worth, although some sources, including Wikipedia, use a definition that implies $0$ is purely imaginary, I have never heard encountered this idea, at least in the US. Seems very strange. I think most people in the US would define a purely imaginary numbers as a nonreal complex numbers whose square is real

One problem is a desire to say 'real' and 'imaginary' are distinct -- "you can't be both!", people will say. But of course you can. No one would say "A point in the plane cannot lie on both the x-axis and the y-axis," especially when shown the point $(0,0)$. But because "real" and "imaginary" also have strongly-associated meanings in most natural languages, there's a temptation (for some folks) to mirror their distinction when defining terms in mathematics. I personally think that's a bad idea, but I'm neither your teacher nor your textbook's author. It seems like a bad question to me.

$0$ is not imaginary. $0 \in \mathbb R$

Thought: If 0 + bi is not purely imaginary then I suggest that NO number can be purely imaginary. Yes?

If I paste (0,0) from above the characters should be zeros but appear as o's. Why?|| Same if I type zeros eg 0000000 0 0 0 00  0 000 . All are zeros.

@RussellMcMahon This is just a font thing. This font uses old-style / "lowercase" numerals; as a result, the letter o and the number 0 look similar. They aren't exactly the same though: the o is skinnier. Here's a string of 0s with one o: 00000000o000000

@Snared Yeah, but $0\in i\mathbb{R}$ too. That's why it's dependent on how the specific class and textbook defines it. Myself, I'd say it's the only number that's both real and imaginary.

BTW, I wouldn't recommend going to your teacher and saying "Math.SE says you're wrong."  They may not appreciate that.  I'd probably go with "Could you explain this to me?  Especially considering our definition of 'imaginary'."

I plan on consulting with him tomorrow. I will definitely hear out his reasoning first, and explain my reasoning/approach to the question.

I would not complain about your teacher's "wrong", but ask him for his definition.

@Deusovi Thanks. My zeros tonight are more distinct! oooo0000. || Last night I could copy and paste zeros from other comments and they would change appearance when I hit enter.

Really it depends on your definition of a purely imaginary number.
If your definition is the same as wikipedia's ie the product of $i$ and any real number (ie any number lying on the ordinate line in the complex plan)
But some definitions exclude 0, see this question
In conclusion I would suggest you go to the class material, find the exact definition given by your professor, and see if 0 fits it.

Or check the textbook for the definition.

Thanks for the answer, I will go through the textbook again, that we follow in class and make sure to read over the chapter on complex numbers again. Although I dont recall an explicit definition for a purely imaginary number.

My personal opinion is that a purely imaginary number should not be real, i.e. should have the form $bi$ with $b \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. But it seems that my opinion is a minority view; most other people do regard $0$ as a purely imaginary number because its real part is $0$.
Let me quote from page 1 of Lars Ahlfors's classic monograph "Complex Analysis":

1.1. Arithmetic Operations. From elementary algebra the reader is acquainted with the imaginary unit $i$ with the property $i^2 = -1$. If the imaginary unit is combined with two real numbers $\alpha, \beta$ by the processes of addition and multiplication, we obtain a complex number $\alpha + i\beta$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the real and imaginary part of the complex number. If $\alpha = 0$, the number is said to be purely imaginary; if $\beta = 0$, it is of course real. Zero is
the only number which is at once real and purely imaginary.

Lars Ahlfors is an important figure in mathematics. Quote from Wikipedia:

His book Complex Analysis (1953) is the classic text on the subject and is almost certainly referenced in any more recent text which makes heavy use of complex analysis.

Your answer complies with Ahlfors. However, your teacher marked it as wrong, and I conclude that he supports my point of view and gave a formal definition somewhere. So do not worry. Be aware that in mathematics many things are not as standardized as one might expect and learn to be flexible  and attentive concerning definitions.

Another example of  a "contraversial" question is whether $0$ is a natural number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number.
